# Rails - how to access a file that is protected by login & password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, authentication, download

On a URL is accessible a file that I want to download. The problem is, that I can access this file on a URL only when I am logged in to the service.

How to download a file from a URL that is protected by login (I have the credentials)? In PHP would be maybe to do it with using cURL, how to do that in Ruby?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read `HTTP` basic authentification docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Basic+Authentication

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?key=value')

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get into a site that doesn't just have basic authentication, you should probably look into [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). For example (taken [from a railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize) on the subject), you might do something like this:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

agent.get("http://railscasts.tadalist.com/session/new")
form = agent.page.forms.first
form.password = "secret"
form.submit

agent.page.link_with(:text => "Wish List").click
```